# How to handle dynamic database with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

We are developing a web application where we are using mongodb as our database. Our app is about field management solutions.

So, in our app the data changes constantly, like, the Admin might want to add a new field to "Employee" Schema or remove it, same goes with many other schemas in the application.

Suppose, after we launch our application, we might introduce a new service where we want to add it to our database, but, the fields required here are different from previous services, and in transactions schema we might want to remove or add a new field.

The next level is we have a schema builder on front end where we create, edit and delete new schemas based on the requirement instead of changing code, it must be dynamic. Now how should i handle these many changes in a production server without restarting and dropping database. **Also the schema builder will have relational data.**

**How to handle relational data with dynamic schemas and middleware function in mongoose?**

Also, i saw in MongoDB documentation that in production mode we are to disable `autoIndex`. So what is the alternative way.

Also in schema sometime we might have to change SchemaOptions like: `unique, minLength, maxLength, requried, etc.,` based on the requriements.

I tried many ways to implement this, but I can't figure out a way to do it in a proper way. `dropIndex` doesn't work, `createIndex` doesn't work.

Whenever i make changes to schema, either I have to drop database or restart my server.

Also after i have 100 documents saved to collection with a field unique to false and if I change unique to true how to handle the previous documents which were saved with unique to false?

Can anyone give me the best example of implementation?
**Can mongoose do my job? Or Should I use JOI with MongoDB Driver for Nodejs without mongoose?**

Thanks.

Comment: Ok your question has multiple questions in it, Also you need not to provide skypeid in question as here users don't usually write entire code, they solve couple of issues(maybe start a discussion chat), Please update your question with specific issue(Otherwise there are high chances of this question gets closed or put in hold) or raise multiple questions only if those weren't answered before :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Love this question it basically build the app for me

Anyway jokes aside your asking a lot of questions here, more than one that could be answered in one simple answer, however, I will give you a place to start.

First I would steer away from Mongoose. You are going to need dynamic schemas and Mongoose is all about having a schema.

Go with MongoDB Native Driver and Joi for object validation.

I would recommend starting with figuring out documents (objects) base key: values that will always be there e.g _id

Then I would build endpoints for creating/updating object validation with Joi and keeping tracking of versions, maybe even keep track which validation each document (object) used when it was created.

Then store the object validation methods in the database or on the server your call there, and that way when an object is created and updated you have access to dynamic object validation.

Unfortunately, you have asked a lot and so these are just a few ideas of the top of my head. I hope it helps. I did also write a blog post about Mongoose:

https://medium.com/better-programming/mongoose-vs-the-mongodb-node-driver-7dc59f00a5dd?source=friends_link&sk=94055c33491efc5578169c8dba586f44